# How to access the return value from a store.filter in extjs?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-stores

I have the following code, where Im creating a store and querying it on load by passing the name_holder value. So bascially the query would be

```
 /query/name:name_holder*
```

where the name_holder value is entered by the user.  Now im trying to retrieve the returned record value but I'm not able to access it outside the store.load function. 
Is my approach even correct? Im new to ext.js and any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
var store = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
                    fields: [
                             {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
                             {name: 'id',  type: 'string'},

                         ],
                    proxy : name_proxy,
                });

var data_names= store.load({
                    params : {
                        query : name_holder
                    },
   callback: function(records, operation, success) {
                            if (success) {
                                var data_id=  records[0].data.id;
                             } else {
                                console.log('error');
                            }
                        }
                });
    console.log(data_id);
```

I can access the data_id value inside the function, but not outside. Hence the console.log line gives me an error.

Comment: The purpose of the function is to check whether or not the record matches the filter condition. Once the filter is complete, the store will have only the things that matched the filter.

Comment: Loading the store with `query: name_holder` would already return records matching the filter condition only, so why filtering?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli is there a way to access the matched data?

Comment: @DrakeES It's basically returning every record that contains the string. I want to filter it to only the records that have exactly the name_holder.

Comment: @pal why split the filtering job between server and client getting each of them do only half of it? Couldn't you just get the server return exact match only as required?

Comment: @DrakeES yeah my approach does seem tedious. Could you suggest an alternative way?

Comment: As I said above, after filtering, the matching records are in the store. So for example you could use `each` to loop the store. Or `getAt` to get at a particular index.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Can you comment on the updated code? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the actual task is to find out the `id` of the record whose `name` exactly matches a given string, then you don't need the whole fuss with stores. Just get your server side API return the ID in response to query like `/query/name:name_holder`. Simply implement an AJAX request to get the ID.

If you need to stick with stores for some reason, then the best would be, again, get the server side to perform exact match so that it returns only one record when `/query/name:name_holder` is requested. In this case your store will have only one record upon loading, and you'll easy find its `id` this way: `store.getAt(0).getId()`.

Finally, if you can't or don't want to touch anything on the server side, use the [query](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-query) method to filter out the record of your interest:

```
store.query(
         'name',
         name_holder,
         false, // not anymatch
         true, // case sensitive
         true // exact match
     ).getAt(0).getId();
```

Example with local data: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/pbo

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried the code that you suggested.. I keep getting an error `store.query` is not a function.

Comment: Post a fiddle. The `query` method on `Ext.data.Store` is available since 1.1.0.

Comment: Im using version 4.0.7

Comment: Post a fiddle or at least your complete code. The `query` method certainly exists in `Ext.data.Store`, so your problem could be wrong scope or something like that.

Comment: I went ahead and removed the filter and directly got the data from store.load. Now the problem I have is that Im not able to retrieve it outside the function call. here is my code. 

    `var data_names= store.load({
                    params : {
                        query : name_holder
                    },
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
              if (success) {
               var data_id =  records[0].data.id;
               } else {
                  console.log('error');
              }
          }
                    });`

Comment: Now your question has nothing to do with ExtJS. It's all JavaScript basics. In a nut shell, you don't "retrieve it outside the function call". Instead, you make the function do what you need because it is a callback of an asynchronous request. Also, there's no point assigning the result of calling `store.load` to `var data_names` just because the result is the store itself! I suggest you read the [doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/source/AbstractStore.html#Ext-data-AbstractStore-method-load) first.